# How to loop through datatable and create table dynamically in ASP.Net MVC razor view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to make my razor code more dinamically. I have more than 100 columns with also more than 100 rows in the datatable (dr).

```
<table id="PS3" class="report">
<tr id="Parameter_name">
<td id="stick_no" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Stick No</td>
<td id="pos" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Pos</td>
<td id="id" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>ID</td>
<td id="type" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Type</td>
<td id="packing_datetime" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Packing DateTime</td>
</tr>

@if (ViewData["AllEmpData"] != null)
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in (ViewData["AllEmpData"] as System.Data.DataTable).Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @dr["stick_no"]
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @dr["pos"]
            </td>
            <td>
                @dr["id"]
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @dr["type"]
            </td>
            <td>
                @dr["packing_datetime"]
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

I would like to do something like this in the foreach cycle :

```
for(i=0; i< column_number; i++){
        <td>
            @dr[column_id[0].toString()]
        </td>
}
```

Where the column_number is the number of column in the id="Parameter_name" row.
So in generally I don't want to write down all of the parameter in the foreach section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Columns` property of `DataTable`. like this:

```
<table id="PS3" class="report">
    <tr id="Parameter_name">
        <td id="stick_no" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Stick No</td>
        <td id="pos" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Pos</td>
        <td id="id" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>ID</td>
        <td id="type" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Type</td>
        <td id="packing_datetime" bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>Packing DateTime</td>
    </tr>

    @if (ViewData["AllEmpData"] != null)
    {
        var dt = ViewData["AllEmpData"] as System.Data.DataTable;

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@dr[col.ColumnName].ToString()</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

You can create the table headers this way as well. But you should consider converting the `DataTable` to a list in the controller and use it in the `View`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did what I was looking for. This should be marked as the answer in my opinion. Cheers